# Separating countries into tropical versus non-tropical R

Tags: r

I have a data frame where one of the column variable is the country. As an example see the vector with the countries.

`country=c("Argentina", "Bahamas", "Barbados", "Belize", "Bolivia", "Brazil", "Virgin Islands", "Chile", "Colombia", "Costa Rica", "Cuba", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "El Salvador", "French Guiana", "Guadeloupe", "Guatemala", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Jamaica", "Martinique", "Mexico", "Nicaragua", "Panama", "Paraguay", "Peru","St Lucia", "St Vincent", "Suriname", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Uruguay", "Venezuela", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", "Brunei", "Cambodia", "India", "Indonesia", "Laos", "Malaysia", "Myanmar", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Philippines", "Papua New Guinea", "Singapore", "SriLanka", "Thailand", "TimorLeste", "Vietnam", "Angola", "Benin", "Botswana", "BurkinaFaso", "Burundi", "Cameroon", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Congo","Djibouti", "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Ethiopia", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Ghana", "Guinea","Guinea Bissau", "Ivory Coast", "Kenya", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Mauritania", "Mali", "Mozambique", "Namibia","Niger", "Nigeria", "Rwanda", "Sudan", "Senegal", "Sierra Leone", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Sudan", "Swaziland", "Tanzania", "Togo", "Uganda", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe", "Canada", "United States of America", "Albania", "Andorra", "Austria", "Belgium", "Bosnia", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Iceland", "Ireland", "Italy", "Liechtenstein","Luxembourg", "Macedonia", "Malta", "Montenegro", "Netherlands", "Norway", "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Serbia", "Slovakia","Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "United Kingdom", "Afghanistan", "Algeria", "Bahrain", "Cyprus", "Egypt", "Iran","Iraq", "Israel", "Jordan", "Kuwait", "Lebanon", "Libya", "Morocco", "Oman", "Qatar", "Saudi Arabia", "Syria", "Tunisia", "Turkey","United Arab Emirates", "Western Sahara", "Yemen", "Armenia", "Azerbaijan", "Belarus", "Estonia", "Georgia", "Kazakhstan", "Kyrgyzstan", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Moldova", "Russia", "Tajikistan", "Turkmenistan", "Ukraine", "Uzbekistan", "Japan", "Mongolia", "North Korea", "South Korea","China", "Australia", "Cook Islands", "Fiji", "French Polynesia", "Micronesia", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Niue", "Samoa", "Solomon Islands", "Tonga", "Vanuatu")`

I would like to separate these countries into tropical versus non-tropical (i.e. those within the tropical region and those that are outside. Does anyone have an idea of how can do this in R?

Comment: We'll first you need the classification data.

Comment: I did a simple google search for list of tropical countries, and the first hit came up with a page that allowed you to downlad it in a data friendly format. You should give it a try and then come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sirius mentioned in the comments, there are lists like the following:

The `csvData.csv` can be downloaded here:
https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/tropical-countries

```
tropical_data <- read.csv("csvData.csv")

# tropical country (71)
country[country %in% tropical_data$country]

# non tropical country (115)
country[!country %in% tropical_data$country]
```